# Table Formatting in Excel 2007: How do I remove it?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, formatting

I've used the new Table Formatting option in Excel 2007. Now I can't remove it. I've dragged the little blue square up to the last cell on the top left, but it just won't go any further. In fact it just won't go at all.

Clear all doesn't remove it. What does? I want my table back! I'm not a beginner with Excel, but this little annoyance has made me feel like on.

Surely there must be some way to remove table format without deleting something or clearing all!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

"Convert to Range" should convert it to normal ranges. Right click on a cell in table and select Table -> Convert to Range. You would need to remove the formatting manually.

Comment: Finally got around to trying this and it works. Many thanks for your insight.

Comment: Alternate click path, use the Table Design tab, see http://superuser.com/a/876310/16966

Answer (score 2):

Try selecting the entire sheet (click box with the arrow in to the left of "A", and above "1") and then try clear all again.

Comment: But I don't want to lose my data! If I clear all I imagine that's what's going to happen.

Comment: No no, I mean the clear all formatting :). Make a copy of the file first if you think we might be talking about two different options though!

Comment: Alternativley hit Ctrl+A, Ctrl+C, open a new worksheet, right click cell A1, click paste special, click "Values" and click ok.

Should give you all your data with no formatting.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to pull this off by highlighting the entire table and then right click and choose Format Cells.  Then go through and remove colors and borders and any filling and you will effectively remove the table and keep all data intact.

Comment: But you've only removed the look of the table. The actual table is still there.

Comment: Did you try Right click on the table, click Table > Convert to Range as Shaji recommends?

Answer (score 1):

If you have MATLAB:

This is really only useful if you use MATLAB often and is usually open. Make sure your Excel file isn't open when attempting this code. Nothing will happen to your data don't worry because the code won't run.

1. Change MATLAB path to where your .xls or .xlsx file is located
2. `>> [~,~,a] = xlsread('yourfile.xls')`
3. `>> xlswrite('yourfile.xls',a)`

Table removed!

Notice I used 'yourfile.xls'. Change this to 'yourfile.xlsx' if your file is a .xlsx file.

Answer (score 1):

1. Click anywhere in the table.

   Tip: This displays the `Table Tools`, adding the `Design` tab.
2. On the `Design` tab, in the `Tools` group, click `Convert to Range`.

Excel Ribbon Image

Note: Table features are no longer available after you convert the table back to a range. For example, the row headers no longer include the sort and filter arrows, and structured references (references that use table names) that were used in formulas turn into regular cell references.

Comment: don't know why this was downvoted, it is a correct and working answer.

Answer (score 0):

1. Select the whole table.
2. Click in the Styles tab `Format Table`.
3. Select at the button `New Table Style...`.
4. Select `First Column Stripe`.

It will create at the top of all the styles a white box Custom style.
Click on this and the format you previously had will disappear.

It works for me....

Answer (score 0):

If using Excel 2010: highlight the cells in the table; go to Home / Editing / Clear / **Clear Formatting**.
Then remove the Filter as well.
[image]

Answer (score -1):

1. Highlight the table and copy to clipboard.
2. Open temporary worksheet
3. Paste as unformatted text.
4. Recopy unformatted table back into main document.